# How to modify mysql alias for MYSQL EXISTS to 0 and 1 as for records in joined mysql table?

Tags: mysql, join

I have **two mysql** tables one as `products` and other is `featured_product`.

product table has all the details about my products including `product_id` as **primary key**.
In my featured_product, i only store **product_id** which is stored only the product_ids of my featured products.

I want to get the all records from the products table and join them with featured_product table.

My problem is when i joined the two tables i received the `product_id` for the rows which i have featured and other rows returned `NULL`.
Is there any way that i can use **alias** like `feature_status` and retrieve `1` for **featured rows** and `0` for non featured?
Thanks a lot

```
**products**         **featured_product**
product_id           product_id 
product_name
product_price

product_id    product_name     product_price  feature_status
1              kids Toy          10                NULL
2              Red Pen            5                2
```

I need instead of this

```
product_id    product_name     product_price  feature_status
    1              kids Toy          10                0
    2              Red Pen            5                1
```

Comment: Please provide sample data from both tables and the desired output.

Comment: @KenWhite sorry for the misatke my friend. I edited it

Comment: Looks like you need to use `CASE WHEN feature_status IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE feature_status AS feature_status`.. It always helps to provide sample data and the expected output and your efforts to solve the problem yourself (meaning your SQLstatement).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just select `featured_product.product_id IS NOT NULL AS feature_status`